# ColorField for ExtJS 4.0

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

Do you know any ColorField implementation for ExtJS 4.x?

I try to create my own (looking DateField source code) but the picker background is transparent and I can't fix it :(

[image]

This is how I create color picker:

```
Ext.create('Ext.picker.Color', {
    pickerField: me,
    ownerCt: me.ownerCt,
    renderTo: document.body,
    floating: true,
    hidden: true,
    focusOnShow: true,
    listeners: {
        scope: me,
        select: me.onSelect
    },
    keyNavConfig: {
        esc: function() {
            me.collapse();
        }
    }
```

P.S. I ask here, because on Sencha Forum I never get an (even a single) answer

Comment: +1 for ###I ask here, because on Sencha Forum I never get a (even a single) answer###

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you try adding something like `style: {backgroundColor: "#ddd"}` into your picker's config?

Comment: I tried but this is the result: http://www.sencha.com.s3.amazonaws.com/forum/ColorField2.png

Comment: here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/4uR2x/1/) where you can see that using `style: {backgroundColor: "#fff"}` is making picker non-transparent

Comment: This website is incredible :) It will be better if it also have a border. The perfect looking is this one http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.menu.ColorPicker

Comment: @ju, I haven't come up with something better than [this](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/4uR2x/5/)

Comment: It seems very good, if no better solutions is found I will mark your answer as correct :)